# How to get Authorization_code and access_Token and send envelope DocuSign using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms, docusignapi, access-token

I am trying to send envelope using **docuSign**, but having error while get `authorization_code` which need to get `access_Token`.

Please help me to get `authorization_Code` and `access_Token`.

I am using ASP.Net web forms and .NET framework 4.5.2

- DocuSign.eSign.dll  5.2.0
- DocuSign.Integration.Client.dll 1.7.2

Request:
`https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=4f464e25-6425-4ea6-915b-aa9bac5b8ce7&redirect_uri=https://account-d.docusign.com/ds/login?authType=JWT`

Response:
`The redirect redirect_uri is not registered properly with DocuSign`

```cs
string RedirectURI = "https://account-d.docusign.com/ds/login?authType=JWT";
string ClientSecret = "****";
string IntegratorKey = "****";


 Uri oauthLoginUrl = GetAuthorizationUri(IntegratorKey, scopes, RedirectURI, OAuth.CODE, null);    
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(oauthLoginUrl);
 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

public Uri GetAuthorizationUri(string clientId, List<string> scopes, string redirectUri, string responseType, string state = null)
{
    string formattedScopes = (scopes == null || scopes.Count < 1) ? "" : scopes[0];
    StringBuilder scopesSb = new StringBuilder(formattedScopes);
    for (int i = 1; i < scopes.Count; i++)
    {
        scopesSb.Append("%20" + scopes[i]);
    }

    UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("https://account-d.docusign.com")
    {
        Scheme = "https",
        Path = "/oauth/auth",
        Port = 443,
        Query = BuildQueryString(clientId, scopesSb.ToString(), redirectUri, responseType, state)
    };
    return builder.Uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that the specified redirect URI is configured under the redirect URI section for the integration key that is being used. Please keep in mind that the same exact redirect URI has to be used when using your authentication URL.

The specified section is found under Settings > Apps and Keys > Click on your integration key > Edit

I would also recommend creating a new integration key, since you have shared it publicly on this thread.

Comment: Thank you Gloriana Marin ...actually that issue was solved. But how to find code value from response or from where I get the code value which need to get accessToken. GenerateAccessToken(IntegratorKey, ClientSecret, code).

Comment: Hi Swap, this would be the authorization code that you received from the callback from when you request the authorization code. This is found in the first step of this documentation Step 1. Request the authorization code: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/

Comment: Thank you Gloriana Marin, i refereed this document and generated request as above but not getting response as mentioned in this document. So that I am unable to get value code. 
Can you please tell me Where could I found the value of code? or where it is present?

Comment: Hi Swap, in order to assist further with this, please open a case at support.docusign.com